# Kohana and Zencart

Tags: php, kohana, zen-cart

I have a kohana script which the customer wants to use in conjunction with a number of zen-cart modules. One idea I had was to run that script and zen-cart side by side with this class.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4912-PHP-Manage-users-of-Zencart-installation.html

Has anyone used this before? Is this a viable option? If not my options are port zen-cart modules to kohna (ugh) or rewrite the kohana script in zen-cart (double ugh).

Answer (score 0):

I would think a much easier path would be to create a model for the Zencart customer object using the in-built ORM module in Kohana. Although all this depends on what your current Kohana script does. Can you post the code for your Kohana script, or at least provide an overview of it's functionality?

Porting a Zencart module to Kohana would be a better option because:

1. Kohana is a much better framework than the mess that is Zencart.
2. You can release that ported code to the community to allow other developers to take advantage of it (and improve your code).

Comment: Here is the kohana script:
http://www.ndot.in/products/auctions-opensource-bidding-application/
and I'm using this http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4912-PHP-Manage-users-of-Zencart-installation.html. I'm having a problem getting the sessions to work together.

Comment: Would building a model allow me to link to zencart from kohana, and let users add to cart and checkout? Thanks.